# How can I import all local repositories to gitlab automatically?

Tags: git, import, gitlab

I have 120 repos in my window server with bonobo.

Yesterday, I've set new Linux server and I've installed **gitlab** in new server. I want to import all repos from old window server in to new gitlab server automatically. Making remote repo in gitlab and pushing old repo is too cumbersome.

I cannot find any solution in internet. What can I do?

Comment: If you have Bash (MinGW/MSYS2/Git Bash/whatever) you can use something in spirit of `find ~/Development -type d -name .git -print | xargs dirname | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'cd "{}" && git remote origin set-url git.example.org/user/$(basename "{}") && git push'` (**caution**: this will break on submodules! extra refining is necessary if you have any). If you don't - install, or write a Windows program that does essentially the same. And beware, this is a rough sketch - don't run it as-is (an even better advice is to never run random code snippets from the Internets).